# Problem Connecting to OutLook 2007(IMAP server) using ChilKat

Tags: c#

I am getting the fallowing error when i am trying to connect to the IMAP outlook mail box programatically(i am able to connect the server but not able to login). I am 100% confident that i am using the correct username and password.

loginResponse: aaac NO Login Failed
  received failed login response from IMAP server
Failed

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Hello.
Have you found the answer already?
After migration from 2003 to 2010 i`m having the same issue.
I`m using ssl on port 993.
I can connect to the server, but cannot login?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Chilkat component, even if your license key is not valid also you will get same error.
Please look at the

```
Component.LastErrorText
```

which will have the detals.

Try

```
        Chilkat.Imap imap = new Chilkat.Imap();
        imap.UnlockComponent("LicenseText");

        // If your IMAP server needs SSL, set the Ssl property = true
        // and set the IMAP port to 993.
        // imap.Ssl = true;
        // imap.Port = 993;
        imap.Connect("IP Address");

        // Login to an email account.
        bool b = imap.Login("username", "password");
```

Comment: loginResponse: aaac NO Login Failed received failed login response from IMAP server Failed........this is  what it says :(

Comment: DLL Date Dec 22 2010
 UnlockPrefix: Anything for 30-day trial
  User Name:abc
  Component: .Net 2.0
  login "username"
  ConnectionType:Unencrypted TCP/IP
 loginResponse: aaac NO Login Failed
  received failed login response from IMAP server
Failed

Comment: Are you sure your username and password is correct? Also check the accessibility to that from the place you are working. May you explain what you mean by OutLook 2007 IMAP Server?

Comment: this is exactly what i have used.....but still getting the error........but i  thing........when u said  imap.Connect("IP Address"); i can use the server name instead of IP Address or i need to use only the IP address???

Comment: Try IP, also Outlook2007 is just client right?. Why you mentioned Outlook 2007 IMAP server? ....Just for my understanding.

Comment: on the outlook 2007 iam able to login to the mailbox and see the mails.........and on the same machine i am working....is that fine or do i need to more access permissions?

Comment: just to mention its not MAPI it is IMAP

Comment: No, If you can login using outlook, then you should be able to access from your application too.Can you check your port

Comment: Yaa, I have also used the same component, But I had no issue in connecting using the above given code.

Comment: Is there any way you can put your code, I Will check that with my IMAP server.

Comment: Are you using SSL certificate?

Comment: If you are not using ssl certificate remove the line                    imap.Port = 993;                         imap.Ssl = true;

Answer (score 0):

Chilkat.Imap imap = new Chilkat.Imap();

```
            bool success; //string responseString;

            // Anything unlocks the component and begins a fully-functional 30-day trial.
            success = imap.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial");
            if (success != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(imap.LastErrorText);
                return;
            }

            imap.Port = 993;
            imap.Ssl = true;
            // Connect to an IMAP server.

            success = imap.Connect("servername.na.company.org");
            if (success != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(imap.LastErrorText);
                return;
            }
            success = imap.IsConnected() ;
            MessageBox.Show("suc"+success);


            success = imap.Login("username", "pwd");


            if (success != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(imap.LastErrorText);
                return;
            }

            // Select an IMAP mailbox
            success = imap.SelectMailbox("firstname.lastname@xxxx.com");
            if (success != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(imap.LastErrorText);
                return;
            }
```